# custom style file style.css attached in drupal theme, but not working

Tags: javascript

Flow to setup files in drupal for easy integration and Manage.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your (unformatted) syntax, it's safe to assume you're referring to a D8 site.

It looks like you've defined a "Library" called "custom-style" in your THEME_NAME.libraries.yml file.

In your THEME_NAME.info.yml file you'll need to include the newly defined library, like so:

```
libraries:
  - THEME_NAME/custom-style
```

This will include the library on every page (that uses this theme) on the site. For more specific uses/scopes (individual pages, etc) you can refer to the docs: https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/assets